# ViewBag RuntimeBinderException (MVC 4, ASPX)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I started up a Default MVC 4 project using the `ASPX` engine (not Razor), and everything works fine.
I can use

`<% Model.Name %>`

and

`<% Model.Rating %>`

for book ratings (instead of the Restaurant Review that is up on the asp.net/mvc tutorials site).  However, my code errors on the 
`<% ViewBag.Message %>`

...so for some reason, when inheriting from the "BookReviewer" Class within the BookReview model, I can view the Model information but not the `Viewbag`?  Am I missing something?  Code below.

[Controller]
HomeController.cs:

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        var model = new BookReview()
        {
            Name = "Pro jQuery For Noobs",
            Rating = 7
        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

[Model]
BookReview.cs

```
    namespace Bookreview.Models
    {
            public class BookReview
            {
                    public string Name { get; set; }
                    public int Rating { get; set; }
            }
    }
```

[View]
Index.aspx:

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<BookRevew.Models.BookReviewer>" %>
    <asp:Content ID="indexFeatured" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent" runat="server">
        <h2>
            <% ViewBag.Message %>
            <% Model.Name %>
            <% Model.Rating %>
        </h2>
    </asp:content>
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere where you are setting `ViewBag.Message`. Nor do I see a `BookReviewer` class you mention. Is there code you're not posting?

Comment: I set it in another ActionResult:
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "This is a test";
        return View();
    }

Is it not allowed to be referenced outside of other ActionResults?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As we can see by your comments, you are setting the `ViewBag.Message` in another controller. The `ViewBag` is **only for data for the view that was set by the controller that served the view**.

If you need to send it from another controller, you should use a parameter in your action method, then you can set the `ViewBag.Message` to the passed in parameter.

Comment: Thank you, that makes much more sense than the way that I had read it in my book.

Comment: Phrased like that that is technically not quite true. You can ofc. go `var otherController = new OtherController(); return otherController.Whatever()` and the view will have access to the data placed in the ViewBag by the original controller. So it's not that "set by the controller serving the view". But rather: In Index() excution path it has never been set. To confirm this, one can set a breakpoint on the line that sets the Viewbag.Message. When debugging, it won't be hit.