# 'System.Dynamic.DynamicObject' does not contain a definition for 'PropertyName'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've faced with the next problem:

I'm trying run .NET MVC site to use ViewBag for passing some data to my View.
Here is the method where I setting the VeiwBag.

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Start()
{
    ViewBag.BanReason = null;
    int userId;

    //Request with UserId, display ban reason if necessary
    if (Request.Params["UserId"] != null && int.TryParse(Request.Params["UserId"], out userId))
    {
        ViewBag.BanReason = CheckIfUserBanned(userId);
    }

    ViewBag.Users = MvcApplication.Users;

    return View();
}
```

When I assign value to the ViewBag (for example ViewBag.BanReason = null;) I've got the RuntimeBinderException with the message

> 'System.Dynamic.DynamicObject' does not contain a definition for
>   'BanReason'.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 with .NET 4.5 and local IIS server with ApplicationPool with .NET 4.0. On the other computer with the same configuration all works nicely and no exceptions is thrown.

Please don't advice to use other techniques like ViewData[""] and Creating a separate model, I don't want to change code that works nicely on the other machine.

I think this is miss-configuration issue. Any guesses will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: show us code where are you using `ViewBag.BanReason`

Comment: It's using in the Start.cshtml
@if (ViewBag.BanReason != null)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        showErrorPanel("@ViewBag.BanReason");
    </script>
}

Comment: Can you post a stack trace?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/jWBJiTSn

Answer (score 48):

your code is fine, ViewBag is having a Dynamic Properties, and in Runtime all the properties are being assigned.

This Exception is a common CLR Exception.. Try doing the Following steps it will work I hope.
Open Visual Studio

- Debug --> Exceptions --> (Uncheck) Common Language Runtime Exceptions

if still problems occures

- Tools --> Options --> Debugging(Expand) --> General --> (Check) Enable Just My Code

hope it helps, its working for me

[Click Here for Detailed Images](http://jimlynn.wordpress.com/2010/04/15/why-does-visual-studio-always-break-on-user-handled-exceptions/)

Comment: I think the core problem here though is that the DynamicObject is using try/catch like an if/else, which doesn't scale for performance, it'll destroy your CPU especially in loops.

Comment: @KellyElton I agree. The CLR seems to have a habit of internally relying on "expected" exceptions. It's a pretty worrying design practice and makes debugging a major PITA when you can't enable "Just My Code" for other reasons.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2017, you can also go to: Debug -> Options and in the options popup go to Debugging -> General and check the box next to "Enable Just My Code"

Comment: Very nice trick, thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is your problem from another stackoverflow answer:

> As we can see by your comments, you are setting the ViewBag.Message in another controller. The ViewBag is only for data for the view that was set by the controller that served the view.
>
> If you need to send it from another controller, you should use a parameter in your action method, then you can set the ViewBag.Message to the passed in parameter.
>
> [ViewBag RuntimeBinderException (MVC 4, ASPX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615124/viewbag-runtimebinderexception-mvc-4-aspx)

Comment: You still get the same exception?

Comment: Yes, I'm still getting it.